# СМС уведомление через PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sms

Добрый день. Подскажите, что то я поиском не нашел. А все что нашел, почему-то не работает. У меня есть скрипт добавления т редактирование неких данных в БД.
Мне нужно реализовать смс уведомление, при изменении одного из полей в БД. Пусть будет для примера статус - при его смене нужно отправлять уведомление на номер телефона, который также прописан в нужной в строке таблицы.

Comment: И в чем проблема именно?

Comment: Проблема в том, что ни через один сервис не приходит ничего. Через sms.ru пришло.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь сервисом sms.ru.
У сервиса есть примеры для php
На свой номер телефона до 5 смс в день бесплатно